# SQL insert multiple rows into a table using a variable with multiple values as one of the values to insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, col3) [col1 through col3 are non null columns]
VALUES (val1,val2,val3)
```

All vals are uniqueidentifiers.  What I am doing is updating a table that has a unique member id for val1 and a unique ribbon key for val2 and a unique created by key for val3.  What this does on the UI side is assigns a ribbon to a member and has to be created by a member.  What I want to do is assign val2 and val3 to 100 members.  So i wanted to know if I could do a select query that returns the list of 100 member ids and assign that list of ids to a variable which i would use for val1.

when trying to get the variable assigned with all the ids using this:

```
declare @members uniqueidentifier
set @members  = (
Select Members.MemberID from Members
where departmentkey = 'D22CF614-721B-4C15-ABF6-02541CDC7502')
```

[this returns all the members from a particular department of 100 members]

i get this error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

So my first step is to find out how to have this variable @members have assigned the list of member ids. 
Then second step is to assign all those members the ribbon like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, col3) 
VALUES (@members,val2,val3)
```

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?
Let me know if you need more information.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, col3) 
    Select Members.MemberID, val2,val3
    from Members
    where departmentkey = 'D22CF614-721B-4C15-ABF6-02541CDC7502';
```

Don't bother with the variable.